# Add a bookmark to Microsoft Edge bookmark bar with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, browser, microsoft-edge, bookmarks, favorites

I would like to add a bookmarklet to Edge bookmark bar.

By exploring Edge user data, it seems that I could follow this approach:

```
$bk=Get-Content "$env:APPDATA\..\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Bookmarks"  | ConvertFrom-Json
$bk.roots.bookmark_bar.children += $newbk
$bk | ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content  "$env:APPDATA\..\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Bookmarks"
```

For an existing bookmark, values are like follow:

```
$bk.roots.bookmark_bar.children[0]
 
date_added     : 13301408662223632
date_last_used : 0
guid           : d9ab901f-c7b2-4daa-8f22-31147db571ac
id             : 7
name           : Microsoft â€“ Cloud, Computers, Apps & Gaming
show_icon      : False
source         : user_copy
type           : url
url            : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us
```

I do not know, how I should exactly format the `newbk` object.
Also should I recompute `$bk.checksum`?

Comment: The checksum is in the JSON file (the first field). I do not know how to create/format the variable ` $newbk`. Should it be a hash table?

Comment: `$newbk = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{date_added="0",date_last_used="0"}` etc (derived from `$bk.roots.bookmark_bar.children[0].gettype()`; I'd try `$bk.psobject.Properties.Remove('checksum')`; don't forget to add some `-Depth` to `ConvertTo-Json`.

Comment: You should replace `Add-Content` by `Set-Content` to replace the existing file with your modified one. You already read the original file and append to it with `+= $newbk`. There is no point in appending your modified data to the original data again using `Add-Content`, which would just duplicate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where I got so far, thanks to users
[JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) and
[zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42).

```
## Bookmark file
$bmpath="$env:APPDATA\..\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Bookmarks"
 
## New bookmark 
$newbk = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{guid=New-Guid; name="Test Bookmark"; show_icon=$false;
                    source="user_copy"; type="url";
                    url="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us"}
 
## New bookmarklet 
$url = @'
javascript: (() => {
  alert('Hello, World!');
})();
'@
$newbkjs = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{guid=New-Guid; name="Bookmarklet";
                      show_icon=$false; source="user_copy"; type="url"; url=$url}
 
## Read
$bk=Get-Content $bmpath | ConvertFrom-Json

## Add
$bk.roots.bookmark_bar.children += $newbk
$bk.roots.bookmark_bar.children += $newbkjs
$bk.psobject.Properties.Remove('checksum')

## Save
$bk | ConvertTo-Json  -Depth 4 | Set-Content $bmpath
```

**Limitations**
I do not know how to make changes effective immediately.
If Edge is running, you need to close and reopen it.
If Edge is not running, you need to start, close, and start it again.

**Additions**
I haven't tried this, but for more sophisticated bookmarklets, it may be necessary URL encoding.

```
$url = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($url)
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to the accepted answer, you could just add a start/restart to the edge process as part of the bookmark addition to force it to take effect as an option, though admittedly not ideal.  Also this can be used for Chrome as well, path is very similar.

```
"$env:APPDATA\..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks"
```