# Issue with script to inject bookmarks into Edge (Chromium based) and Google Chrome

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, bookmarks

I've got a script that injects bookmarks into Edge or Chrome.  For the most part, it works reasonably well, however, when the browser is relaunched, the **name** of the favorite is stripped out. The bookmark shows up with a blank document icon and no name.  (After going to the site the favicon is added back to the bookmark, so I'm not concerned about that).
**So, my question is how can I get it to not do that?**

When I look at the bookmarks file before launching the browser, the name is there, but after launching the browser, the name is gone. I followed this script: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75642929/add-a-bookmark-to-microsoft-edge-bookmark-bar-with-powershell](https://stackoverflow.com) to create my script.
The relevant parts of my script go like this:

```powershell
$bookmarkPath = "$env:localappdata\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\bookmarks"
$Bookmarks = Get-Content -path $bookmarkpath

$NewBookmark = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    guid = (New-Guid).Guid
    name = 'Name from CSV'
    show_icon = $true
    source = 'user_copy'
    type = 'url'
    url = 'URL from CSV'
}
$Bookmarks.roots.bookmark_bar.children += $NewBookmark
$Bookmarks.psobject.properties.remove('checksum')
Try {
    $Bookmarks | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Set-content -Path $bookmarkPath -force
}
catch {
    $_.exception.message
}
```

As an example, this is what I see:

```json
{
    "roots": {
        "bookmark_bar": {
            "children": [ {
                "date_added": "13353700456516",
                "date_last_used": "0",
                "guid": "eecb133a-98f9-497b-8ab3-692646b7df74",
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Google",
                "show_icon": true,
                "source": "user_copy",
                "type": "url",
                "url": "https://www.google.com"
            }
      ...
}
```

and after launching:

```json
{
    "roots": {
        "bookmark_bar": {
            "children": [ {
                "date_added": "13353700456516",
                "date_last_used": "13353700708627",
                "guid": "eecb133a-98f9-497b-8ab3-692646b7df74",
                "id": "2",
                "name": "",
                "show_icon": true,
                "source": "user_copy",
                "type": "url",
                "url": "https://www.google.com"
            }
      ...
}
```

I'd expect the name to not be stripped out.  I've tried changing the `[pscustomobject]` properties down to the minimum set of properties (`name`, `url`, `type`, `url`) and it still happens.
I get the same result no matter how many bookmarks I add this way.. they all have the name stripped out when the browser gets re-written.

Comment: So the modified JSON looks as expected in the output file _before_ launching the browser and _then_ the names disappear?

Comment: As an aside: the `[ordered]` is unnecessary; `[pscustomobject] @{ ...}` is syntactic sugar that implicitly preserves the definition order.

Comment: Yes.. that's what I was showing - before launch and after launch.
I thought that was the case with the `[ordered]` tag, but I was mainly just basing it on the guys code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this issue with your code. Particularly, I can't even add bookmarks without `ConvertFrom-Json`.

Anyway, I suppose you should change `"show_icon": true` into `false`. `"show_icon": true` means **show icon only**, so there won't be a name displayed for that bookmark.

Comment: That's just a snippet of the code. But I didn't know that's what the  show_icon was supposed to be.  I will test it right now, and if that's the case, then problem solved.

Comment: I changed the `show_icon` to false, and I still see the same behavior.  The name is still being stripped out, even though the bookmarks are visible in the browser.
Thank you again for all the help :-)

Comment: @DavidF If you simply use the original code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75642929/add-a-bookmark-to-microsoft-edge-bookmark-bar-with-powershell, can you reproduce this issue?